# Simplest, lightest Java Web Services engine?

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am looking for this simplest, plainest way to get a Java web service up in the air.  I used to use Axis-1-on-Tomcat, but with Axis 2 its getting too thick.  Some preferences for what I'm looking for:

1. Low memory footprint - A small library with minimal binaries. Axis2.war is 17 MB - I need something lighter.
2. Embedded - Runs from within a JVM with as few as possible configuration files and admin scripts.  Alt., run on top of Jetty (or another embedded HTTP server).
3. If possible, runtime configuration (like Jetty) instead of configuration files.
4. Has Java-to-WSDL and WSDL-to-Java.
5. As simple as possible mechanism to add services. It's OK if the server has to be re-started to detect a new service. Preferably, no lists in files of services to load.

Is anyone familiar with a solution along these lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still recommend to go with **Axis2** - just strip out everything you do not need. "[Single JAR containing all Axis2 client side dependencies](http://blog.afkham.org/2010/06/single-jar-containing-all-axis2-client.html)" and "[Understanding Axis2 dependencies](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-dev@ws.apache.org/msg38002.html)" could be useful starting points.

As embedded HTTP server, I guess **Jetty** is the best option.

Comment: Not perfect, but better then nothing. Thanks for the links! Btw, Axis2 has a fat-but-working standalone server, too.